# Ruby/Nokogiri inspect reveals more then class. I need the extra item inspect shows

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

In the following code:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML($browser.html)
page_links = page.css("a").select
page_links.each do |link|
    if not link.nil?
        if not link['href'].nil? and !!link['href']["/about"]
            puts link.class
            puts link.inspect
        end
    end
end
```

the `link.class` outputs the following:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Element
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb623d3c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb623c7e name="action-type" value="8">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb623c74 name="class" value="a-n g-s-n-aa g-s-n-aa I8 EjFvwd VP">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb623c6a name="target" value="_top">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb623c60 name="href" value="./104882190640970316938/about">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdb623792 "PetSmart Winchester">]>
```

And `link.inspect` outputs the following:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Element
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb623666 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb6235a8 name="action-type" value="8">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb62359e name="class" value="a-n g-s-n-aa g-s-n-aa Gbb EjFvwd VP">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb623594 name="target" value="_top">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb62358a name="href" value="./104882190640970316938/about">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb6230bc name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb62304e name="style" value="height:110px; width:110px;">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb622e1e name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb622db0 name="style" value=" height: 110px; width: 110px;">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb622da6 name="class" value="mja">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x..fdb622d9c name="src" value="https://mts0.google.com/vt/data=TSwRVVf0DGlwBQqarpBU3wUz-i2gqbuWEbxTilWKINf30Au9l0oLM_ojk4KI0oPUi8kL5fJaJWte45O3abOXMzE3L7xDBg">]>]>]>
```

In Nokogiri I can access the link text by `link.content` and the link url by `link['href']` .  Yet neither of these methods work for image source from the inspect results.

How can I get the img `src` within this example code that inspect is revealing?

UPDATE:  HERE IS THE HTML CODE

```
<div class="HWb">
<div class="erb">
    <div class="ubb">
        <div role="button" class="a-f-e c-b c-b-T c-b-Oe c-b-H-ra L0a X9" tabindex="0"
        data-placeid="6817440171144926830" data-source="lo-gp" data-inline="true"
        data-tooltip-delay="600" data-tooltip-align="b,l" data-oid="104882190640970316938"
        data-size="small">
            <span class="TIa c-b-fa"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3 class="drb">
        <a href="./104882190640970316938/about" target="_top" class="a-n g-s-n-aa g-s-n-aa I8 EjFvwd VP"
        action-type="8">PetSmart Winchester</a>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="Qbb">
    <span class="vqb SIa">Pet Store</span>
    <span class="lja SIa">
        <a href="//www.google.com/url?sa=D&amp;oi=plus&amp;q=https://maps.google.com/maps?q%3DPetsmart%2Bloc:22601%26numal%3D1%26hl%3Den-US%26gl%3DUS%26mix%3D2%26opth%3Dplatter_request:2%26ie%3DUTF8%26cid%3D6817440171144926830%26iwloc%3DA"
        target="_blank" class="a-n uqb">2310 Legge Boulevard, Winchester, VA</a>
    </span>
    <span class="SIa">(540) 662-5544</span>
</div>
<div class="crb">
    <div class="Pbb a-f-e">
        <div class="Fbb">
            <div class="cca">
                <div class="tob">
                    <div class="xob">“Do not bother with the grooming salon, the staff are unusually stupid.
                        Otherwise the store is a typical petsmart.”</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dWa">
        <a href="./104882190640970316938/about" target="_top" class="a-n g-s-n-aa g-s-n-aa Gbb EjFvwd VP"
        action-type="8"><div style="height:110px; width:110px;"><img src="https://mts0.google.com/vt/data=TSwRVVf0DGlwBQqarpBU3wUz-i2gqbuWEbxTilWKINf30Au9l0oLM_ojk4KI0oPUi8kL5fJaJWte45O3abOXMzE3L7xDBg" class="mja" style=" height: 110px; width: 110px;"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the HTML that you are running your code against (ie what is the value of $browser.html).

Comment: What Justin answered; why not just use normal XML/HTML processing functionality?

Comment: `inspect` is to give you visibility into the objects created, but isn't for you to use for parsing. Nokogiri is chock-full of parsing goodness to help you access tags and parameters, however, without a sample of the HTML you are parsing we can't give you a very accurate answer. Any attempts to do so are shooting in the dark.

Comment: Please note that link.class does NOT show the IMAGE element.  And link.inspect does NOT show the TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the HTML you're making it a lot harder, but after some digging into the `inspect` output, I think I have a reasonable HTML snippet.

This is how I'd go about getting to the `<img src="...">` tag:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<a action-type="8" class="a-n g-s-n-aa g-s-n-aa Gbb EjFvwd VP" target="_top" href="./104882190640970316938/about">
    <div style="height:110px; width:110px;">
        <img style=" height: 110px; width: 110px;" class="mja" src="https://mts0.google.com/vt/data=TSwRVVf0DGlwBQqarpBU3wUz-i2gqbuWEbxTilWKINf30Au9l0oLM_ojk4KI0oPUi8kL5fJaJWte45O3abOXMzE3L7xDBg">
    </div>
</a>
EOT

doc.at('img')['src'] # => "https://mts0.google.com/vt/data=TSwRVVf0DGlwBQqarpBU3wUz-i2gqbuWEbxTilWKINf30Au9l0oLM_ojk4KI0oPUi8kL5fJaJWte45O3abOXMzE3L7xDBg"
```

You'll need to take the time to improve your question and provide more detail if that doesn't work.

---

If you are not sure whether you will have 0, 1 or 1+ instances of a tag, use `search` because it returns a NodeSet, which acts like an Array, making it easy to deal with no, single or multiple occurrences:

```
doc.search('img').map{ |img| img['src'] }
```

will return all the `<img src="...">` values in the document in an array. You can iterate over those easily or use `empty?` to see if there are no hits:

```
doc.search('img').map{ |img| img['src'] }.each do |src|
  # do something with src if any are found.
end
```

If it's possible you'll have `<img>` tags without the `src="..."` parameter, use `compact` to filter them out before iterating:

```
doc.search('img').map{ |img| img['src'] }.compact.each do |src|
  # do something with src if any are found.
end
```

If you only expect 0 or 1 occurrence, try:

```
src = doc.at('img') && doc.at('img')['src']
```

as in:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body><p>foo</p>
<img src="blah">
<p>bar</p></body></html>
EOT
src = doc.at('img') && doc.at('img')['src']
=> "blah"
```

or, without the `src` parameter:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body><p>foo</p>
<img>
<p>bar</p></body></html>
EOT
src = doc.at('img') && doc.at('img')['src']
=> nil
```

or missing the `<img>` tag entirely:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body><p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p></body></html>
EOT
src = doc.at('img') && doc.at('img')['src']
=> nil
```

If you want to continue to use an `if` block:

```
if doc.at('img')
  puts doc.at('img')['src']
end
```

will accomplish what your:

```
if not doc.at('img').nil?
  puts doc.at('img')['src']
end
```

accomplishes, but in a more straightforward and concise manner, while maintaining readability.

The downside to doing two `at` lookups is it can be costly in big documents, especially inside a loop. You could get all Perlish and use:

```
if (img = doc.at('img'))
  puts img['src']
end
```

but that's not really the Ruby way. For clarity and long-term maintenance, I'd probably use:

```
img = doc.at('img')
if (img)
  puts img['src']
end
```

but that exposes the `img` variable, cluttering up things. It's programmer's choice at that point.

Comment: I got it!  Awesome!  Yes I used this code, but it needs to check for nil.  `if not doc.at('img').nil?; puts doc.at('img')['src']; end'

Comment: Using `nil?` isn't necessary. See my additional content in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your two outputs look like they are two different links (ie both the `link.class` and `link.inspect` for each).

Assuming we are talking about getting the image source in the second output, it looks like the HTML is something like:

```
<a href="href"><div><img src="image_src" /></div></a>
```

Assuming that is true, then you need to do:

```
puts link.at_css("img")['src']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found if you take the results from `link.inspect`, since they are a string, and use regex you can grab the image URL.

```
link.inspect[/http.*com.*"/].chop # Since all other urls are relative ./
```

I don't believe this is the best method.  I will try working with the other answers first.

Comment: Don't use `inspect` for processing. Its format varies depending on the object being inspected and the variables it contains. It's good for looking at an object, but if you need to process the contents of a variable, do it by writing accessors you can count on.